# I want to put a span inside a php file

Tags: php, css

```
<div class="well">
<h2>Top 5 Level</h2>
<?php
$cache = new Cache('engine/cache/topPlayer');
if ($cache->hasExpired()) {
    $players = mysql_select_multi("SELECT `name`, `level`, `experience` FROM `players` ORDER BY `experience` DESC LIMIT 5;");

    $cache->setContent($players);
    $cache->save();
} else {
    $players = $cache->load();
}?> <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<?php

$count = 1;
foreach($players as $player) {
{echo "<TR><TD><strong>$count.</strong></TD>";
echo "<TD><a href='characterprofile.php?name=". $player['name']. "'>". $player['name']. "</a></TD>";
echo "<TD>Lvl.". $player['level'] ."<br></span></TD></TR>";     
    echo '</TR>';}
    $count++;

}

?></table></span>
```

I want to add this `span(span class="label label-info">)` into the third table (`Lvl.". $player['level']`).

I tried a lot of things, but I can't get it working. 
Please help me.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: first of all Lvl.". $player['level']  is not a table its a td

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<TD><span class="label label-info">Lvl.'. $player['level'] .'<br></span></TD></TR>';
```

Changed to single quotes, since you're not using the features of string interpolation, there's no reason to be using double quotes anyway.

The whole thing could be much simpler to read and write. You also have weird extra braces and quotes.

```
foreach($players as $player) {
    $row = <<<ROW <tr>
    <td><strong>$count</strong></td>
    <td><a href="characterprofile.php?name={$player['name']}">{$player['name']}</a></td>
    <td><span class="label label-info">Lvl.{$player['level']}<br></span></td>
    </tr>
ROW;
    echo $row;
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want from this line : `echo "<TD>Lvl.". $player['level'] ."<br></span></TD></TR>";`

to have this? `echo "<TD><span class='label label-info'>Lvl.". $player['level'] ."<br></span></TD></TR>";`